# Trouble compiling and running a basic program in eclipse for android

Tags: android, eclipse

this is a real basic question, but I am having a frustrating time learning how to compile/run an android pong program from a website.  The tutorial I am following is here - http://mikeyhogarth.wordpress.com/2010/10/09/how-to-develop-pong-for-android/

I keep trying, and I am getting errors.  I am new to android (but not programming) so I am having trouble identifying the problem.

Also the tutorial mentions layout.xml, but I do not see a layout.xml in eclipse, I see a main.xml, is that the same thing?

Attached is my screenshot with errors. Suggestions?  Have I configured eclipse/java/android wrong?  Is there a problem with the tutorial?  I appreciate links to any other good game/graphic based starting tutorials you may have to offer.

[Screenshot here](http://i40.tinypic.com/9zqecj.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to add import statements to the classes you've copied from the tutorial.  Double clicking on one of the errors (i.e. SurfaceHolder cannot be resolved to a type) should take you to it's place in the code.  Hovering over where it says SurfaceHolder for a moment should pop-up something that will allow you to "Import 'SurfaceHolder' (android.view)".  Try doing that and see if it starts getting rid of some of those errors.

Comment: thank you!  it seemed like all answers worked, plus he left some import statements out.  My fault for having faith that the tut was right!  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to declare your package in your java files like so:

```
package com.mikey.pong;

public class GameState {

   //screen width and height
    final int _screenWidth = 300;
    final int _screenHeight = 420;
    ....
```

Looks like the tutorial assumed you would provide this.

and yes, your main.xml file is considered a layout, hence living in the layout dir.

Comment: thank you!  it seemed like all answers worked, plus he left some import statements out.  My fault for having faith that the tut was right!  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you didn't import the classes contained in the android SDK to your project. In eclipse, press CTRL+SHIFT+O to invoke the import feature.

Comment: thank you!  it seemed like all answers worked, plus he left some import statements out.  My fault for having faith that the tut was right!  Thanks for your help!